# Size issues in localization $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ category

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories, localization

When one starts with a locally small category $\mathcal{C}$ and wants to localize it at an appropriate choosen collection of morphisms $\mathcal{W}$, then in general one faces some size issues in the localized category $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$. The point is that even if $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ exists, it might show bad behaviour with respect to it's size, eg it might be not more locally small.

It seems that one is eager to avoid this size phenomena wheneven possible, eg one can say that development of rather deep concepts like model categories can be regarded as attept to address this issue.

My questions are rather basic:

1. When one says (as in Charles Weibel's Homological Algebra) that one tries to ignore the "size issues" around the localization $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$, does one really only refer to the aim that "in nice situations" one wants $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ to keep locally small, that's all? Or is there "more" involved?
2. And, why one tries whenever possible to impose conditions on $\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{W}$ to assure that the localization  $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ stays locally small? If not, in what kind of troubles one is running?

Is it just because in the case $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ locally small it is just easier to handle/ work with from pure "practical" point of view, ie that it has "simpler" structure (eg see Gabriel-Zisman Theorem in Weibel's book) or are there structural reasons involved, in the sense that in case $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ not locally small it fail abstractly to satisfy some important category theoretical properties?

For example I saw often that one often wants that the homotopy category (which is a special case of a localization procedure) stays locally small, but why is it so important at the end of the day?

Comment: Yoneda's lemma is not valid for non locally small categories, just because it does not make any sense. Of course you can work with non locally small categories but you have to be very careful with the "size" of the objects to not bump into a contradiction. There are many questions related to this issue already on Mathoverflow by the way.

Comment: besides Yoneda, to which aspects are you refering to when you say to be careful to the size of the involved objects in order not to run into contradictions? What kind of contradictions could occure in this context if I "ignore" the size aspects notoriously? Wrongly assumed of existence of certain (co)limits?

Comment: Proper classes are used every day (the proper class of all sets for exemple); as long as you don't take for example its cardinal to make a calculation with it, it's safe.

Comment: If you ignore sizes you end up getting left and right adjoints for all functors. Besides, it’s not a matter of size but a matter of getting out of the category of sets. Sets have sizes, proper clases don’t.

Comment: At great risk of sounding provocative (and potentially wrong), I'm gonna posit that all of these concerns are ultimately not about category theory in the sense that $ZFC$ (and $GBC$, $MK$, etc.) are all the 'wrong' foundations for category theory, and this foundation mismatch gives rise to these concerns. Working in an 'appropriate' foundation, (e.g. $ZFC+AU$, $ZFC+$'there exist countably many inaccessible cardinals', [higher order set theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.10060), etc.) we have that any category we care about is locally small, relative to some larger stage of collection.

Comment: @AlecRhea Yeah, that’s definitely wrong. For an easier instance, the modified foundations do nothing to make the presheaf category into a free cocompletion monad on all categories. Or, nothing to modify the fact that a large-cocomplete category is a preorder. There is a real and unavoidable mathematical fact that at least two different sizes are needed in category theory.

Comment: That said, as my answer indicates, I do think that size issues are largely insignificant for this particular problem, and maybe that’s all you meant.

Comment: @KevinArlin No, I mean that the issues you mention might be avoided in subtler ways, but I am tired at the moment; for a more specific example of what I do mean that may be refutable, I assert that if you work with any fixed level of collection (call it $n$) then we can consider the $n+1$ collection of all $n$-categories which is itself $n+1$-locally small, an does enjoy nice free cocompletion properties. Yes, we can then complain about the collection of all $n+1$-categories, or the collection of all 'categories' without reference to any level of collection, but my assertion is that even these

Comment: @KevinArlin issues can be ameliorated by once again shifting to a foundation that can provide a model of the previous foundations you were working in; this is clearest, to my mind, thinking about it in terms of the [multiversal foundations](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03169) laid out in a note I wrote last year.

Comment: Some potentially related questions: [What interesting/nontrivial results in Algebraic geometry require the existence of universes?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/24552) [Do Grothendieck universes matter for an algebraic geometer?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/331441) [Are grothendieck universes enough for the foundations of category theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/115099) [Reflection principle vs universes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/382270).

Answer (score 5):

People do always mention the size issue with localizations, but in this particular case I think it’s not so much about size; the failure of local smallness is more primarily a way of expressing how incredibly awful $C[W^{-1}]$ might be in general. If you knew nothing about some localization other than that it turned out to be locally small, I can’t really think of anything that would do for you. The payoff of the theories of calculi of fractions, model categories, etc is not only to get a locally small localization but really to get a localization that can actually be worked with.

Comment: Indeed, being able to compute by means of resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is really an extended comment, to clarify a (potentially tangential) point.

Working in a foundation like $ZFC$, if you have a locally small category $\mathcal{C}$ and a collection of morphisms $\mathcal{W}\subseteq{\bf Hom}_\mathcal{C}$ it is certainly possible that $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ will be a large category, but even in this situation there is hope without drastically altering the concepts under consideration; rather, we can shift the context we consider them in.

Note: everything I'm about to do can be done with inaccessible cardinals or Grothendieck universes.

Working in [higher order set theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.10060) ($HOST$), the defining formula of the sets and functions defining in $\mathcal{C}$ can be used to define a category $\mathcal{C}$ in $HOST$ which is locally $0$-small and $1$-small. The localization $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{W}^{-1}]$ may then be $0$-large, but it will always be $1$-small and we can manipulate $1$-small categories just as easily as $0$-small ones (traditional "small categories"), so long as we remember to pay attention to which level of size we're working with.

Similarly, any category defined in any foundation with finitely many levels of collection which ends up being 'too large' can be reinterpreted in $HOST$ to obtain a version of the same category, appropriately contextualized to make it malleable for our purposes.

Yes, there are still structural facts this approach will never get around (Freyd's classic 'any large cocomplete large category is thin', for example), but all of these facts take on a new light in this setting. Sticking with Freyd, his observation now takes the form "any $n$-cocomplete $n$-large category is thin". We can have (for example) $1$-complete $1$-locally small non-thin categories -- these won't be definable in $ZFC$, but in this setting they are just as well-behaved as the familiar $0$-complete $0$-locally small categories we all know and love.

Yes, we can still ask about categories that are 'large' in this setting in the sense that no level of collection contains them completely, like the category of all collections at all levels, but this situation can once again be ameliorated by shifting foundations (as suggested by the final axiom in my note above). Adding this axiom we can construct a category of $n$-collections for all $n$ (which isn't possible without it), but we still have other large categories -- these can once again be made appropriately small by shifting foundations again, in a way that is clearest for me to think about using the [multiversal foundation](https://arxiv.org/abs/2206.03169) laid out in another note I wrote last year.