# Do algebraic stacks satisfy fpqc descent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stacks, algebraic-stacks

It is known, thanks to Gabber, that algebraic spaces are sheaves in the fpqc topology:

[Stacks project 03W8](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/03W8)

Is the analogous statement for algebraic (Artin) stacks true? If not, is it true under some reasonable hypotheses?

Comment: "analogous statement" has a least two meanings 1 algebraic (Artin) stacks are sheaves in the fpqc topology and better 2 algebraic (Artin) stacks are stacks in the fpqc topology could you clarify ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be helpful to have a look at [these notes](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Sept15-17%28stacks%29.pdf) by Anatoly Preygel (see also [MO/15910/2503](https://mathoverflow.net/a/15910/2503)).  In particular, Proposition 3.3.6 says that an algebraic stack is an fpqc sheaf if the diagonal is quasi-affine.

Comment: Both the question and your answer are ambiguous. Usually by sheaf one means sheaf of sets, whereas here you obviously mean fpqc "sheaf of groupoids", usually called fpqc stack.

Comment: @Niels, for me an algebraic stack is defined to be a sheaf of groupoids (satisfying some conditions), so I interpret the question as whether or not this sheaf satisfies fpqc descent.

Comment: This is not the classical definition, for instance not the definition in the stacks project. What you call sheaf is simply misleading with the current terminology.

Comment: @Niels This is, however, the standard terminology in homotopy theory (sometimes you see them referred as "homotopy sheaves" but the "homotopy" part is dropped more often than not).

Comment: @Denis the question was formulated with a clear reference to the stacks project and to algebraic stacks, so I don't understand the point of your remark.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I don't understand how Adeel's answer can be misleading. In which sense could you misunderstand the sentence "algebraic stacks with quasi-affine diagonal are fpqc sheaves"? Also the fact that it referenced the stacks project does not mean that the person in question is interested mainly in algebraic geometry (even if I admit that's probably the case): homotopy theorists use algebraic stacks all the time!

Comment: @Denis as I already mentioned in the first comment "algebraic stacks with quasi-affine diagonal are fpqc sheaves" is misleading since this can be understood as : a sheaf of sets. That is what most algebraic geometers will understand when you claim a stack is a sheaf. If the answer uses a different terminology than the question, there should be a warning.

Comment: I see your point, but it is not clear to me that the question is using a different terminology than the answer. Anyway I don't think this is worth discussing further

Comment: Thank you very much - this is exactly what I wanted (and I find it hard to see how an algebraic geometer could interpret the claim that "algebraic stacks with quasi-affine diagonal are fpqc sheaves" to mean that they are then forced to be sheaves in sets, but...).